# How can hide wishlist button on all product before login using Yith WooCommerce wishlist plugin?

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce

I want to hide wishlist button on all products before login. I want to disable wishlist button before login on all products and single product page. I have try this in function.php but failed.

```
function login_wishlist(){
    if(is_user_logged_in()) { return true;}else{ return false;}
}
add_action('yith_wcwl_add_to_wishlist', 'login_wishlist');
```

I don't know how can do that, so can any one help?

Answer (score 2):

Try this one and let me know the output.

```
add_filter('yith_wcwl_positions', 'only_show_to_logged_in_user');

function only_show_to_logged_in_user($so_array=array()){
    if(!is_user_logged_in()){
        $so_array   =   array(
            "shortcode" => array("hook"=>'', 'priority'=>0)
        );
    }
    return $so_array;
}
```

**NOTE:** Untested.

**EDITED**

Other quick solution is to hide that if user is not logged in with the jQuery.

```
add_action('wp_footer', 'only_show_to_logged_in_user_1');

function only_show_to_logged_in_user_1(){
    if(!is_user_logged_in()){

        echo "<script>";
            echo "jQuery('.add_to_wishlist').hide();";
        echo "</script>";

    }
}
```

Comment: Which value should i put on "hook"=>'Here Value'

Comment: Just keep it blank ..And tell me what is it giving to you in result ?

Comment: Rohil_PHPBeginner its working only product detail pages, i need to on all pages like homepage and category pages.